# why are not install celery

Tags: python, django, celery

[image: celery warning message]I don't understand that why are not showing all objects in my Django home .

Comment: Actually, your problem is not with the celery installation but with vine.

Comment: Post any relevant text as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the last line `Permission denied`. You are trying to install packages into /usr/local/... not as super user. Either

- use virtual environments (**best solution**)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
  virtualenv ENV_NAME
  source ENV_NAME/bin/activate
  pip install celery
  ```

  or
- install into you home directory

  ```
  pip install --user celery
  ```

  or
- use super user for installation (**worst solution**)

  ```
  sudo pip install celery
  ```

Comment: Now I face this problems:                                                                      (env) nabir@dark:~/env$ sudo pip install celery
[sudo] password for nabir: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal

Comment: Did you try the other solutions without super user?

Comment: it is so nicely self-evident here why you don't even show them the `sudo` solution. they _will_ shoot themselves in the foot straight away.